# New in java (Android). Why does ANT DEBUG show error "cannot find symbol"?

Tags: android, ant, symbols

I'm developing my very first app on Android, and just by following the "Android Training" I ended in this trouble. I did read it's something with the libs, but I really don't understand how to fix it. 
The target for this project is Android 2.3.3 (API 10), and I put the "android-support-v4.jar" in the /libs folder, expecting the ant to compile against it automatically with the Android defaults. 
Not working. Ant tells errors like this one:

```
 .......\test1\ActividadPrincipal.java:20: error: cannot find symbol
 [javac]     public void sendMessage (view view)
 [javac]                              ^
 [javac]   symbol:   class view
 [javac]   location: class ActividadPrincipal
```

Comment: the view is a class and in every language the class name were start with Capital letter.

That's why it shows this error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Welcome to StackOverflow!

Class names start with a capital letter. It cannot find the class view with a non-capital letter.
Make it `(View view)`.

You should also import the `View` class in your Activity (at the top):

```
import android.view.View;
```

Comment: Thank you a lot for your quick answer! I did try that before but with NO sucess. Look:

    \test1\ActividadPrincipal.java:20: error: cannot find symbol
     [javac]     public void sendMessage (View view)
     [javac]                              ^
     [javac]   symbol:   class View
     [javac]   location: class ActividadPrincipal

Comment: lol I know I'm sorry I'm new on this website! I sent the incomplete comment like 5 times...

Comment: That's ok :) not a problem. Please see my updated answer for the import statement. Have you also done that?